# Table выходит за границу родительского блока

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```html
<div class="col-12">

  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Доставка</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Регион доставки</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Стоимость доставки, рубли</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
          <p>Платная</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Санкт-Петербург</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>450</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Ленинградская область</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Индивидуально</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Таблица выходит за границы блока:

[image: Таблица выходит за границы блока]

Как сделать так чтобы таблица имела ту же ширину которую имеет блок col-12 ?
Указывал стили width: 100% для таблицы не помогло.

.table-responsive не предлагать, там появляется прокрутка, а мне она не нужна
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: если слова в ширину не влезают, дак настройте перенос слов соответствующе

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: я может и вообще пошёл не в ту сторону но поиграйся с overflow

Answer (score 0):

Каждая ячейка таблицы заняла минимальную ширину, в данном случае ширину, слова и не может разорвать слово. Не уверен, что это целесообразно, но чисто технически можно сделать вот что

```css
.container { width: 80px; border: 1px solid red }
table { border-spacing: 0 }
td { 
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    padding:0;
    word-wrap: break-word; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table><tr><td>1111111111111111111</td><td>222</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, содержимое просто перескакивает на следующую строку

Comment: @ФлиннТаггарт раз перескакивает, значит ширина ячейки в сумме больше ширины таблицы. Добавьте верстку в вопрос

Comment: добавил. Стили бутстрап, я их не менял

Comment: @ФлиннТаггарт https://jsfiddle.net/ftdnzx9q/ вот ваш вариант

Comment: Dim_K, почти, только без переноса строки

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте правило:

```
table{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Возможно я Вас неверно понял. Вот html и css

```css
table {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Доставка</p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p>Регион доставки</p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p>Стоимость доставки, рубли</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
              <p>Платная</p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p>Санкт-Петербург</p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p>450</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Ленинградская область</p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p>Индивидуально</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Пробовал, не решает проблему

Comment: вы все правильно поняли, структура такая, пробовал указать этот стиль, все равно на мобилках не помещается таблица

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью @media запроса где выставил разные размеры шрифтов на разных разрешениях экрана и теперь все красиво как надо.

Comment: Никогда не используйте таблицу, если хотите адаптивности без прокрутки, так как для "table" - это невозможно. Лучше используйте "display:grid", посидите, помучаетесь конечно, но зато результат будет хороший. А то что вы уменьшили шрифт - это не выход, так как у вас сейчас маленькая таблица, а если будет огроменная на 10 столбцов например???